# How to check if external sd card is there or not in android?

Tags: android, storage, sd-card, android-sdcard

i am using 4.4 moto e.it supports internal sd card and external Sd card.I want to scan media files which is available in external sdcard? if removable media is not available it should fallback to internal media files.

Please help me !!!

Comment: You cannot check it. Android does not provide fuctions for that. You have to let the user indicate a removable sd card if he has. before you do that you could try getExternalFilesDirs() and continue from there on.

Comment: Bear in mind that [you do not have access to the "external sd card" in general](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

Comment: @CommonsWare i saw some file explorer.how they detetcing my internal sdcard and external sdcard  as well?

Comment: Third-party file explorers should not have access to removable media on Android 4.4+. Built-in file explorers may have access, as they were put there by the manufacturer. And you are welcome to use `MediaStore` to access whatever is available in there, which may include the contents of removable media.

Comment: @CommonsWare    ya u r right,Thanks for clarifiying me.I am update my question.I hope that ur answer will helpful for someone